# Javascript date picker asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new working with asp.net and I was very happy about the Html Helper that make editor for dates but I saw that it's not compatible with safari so I decided to use javascript date picker.

So I installed jquery.ui.combined, placed every(maybe too many)render or `<script>` and I tried to make a date picker with the following code but nothing append :

```
<script>
      $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
        $( "#locale" ).change(function() {
          $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",
            $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
        });
      });
    </script>
     //more code 
    <input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Can someone explain why ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: can you reproduce this on jsfiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qvt4zj9x/2/  Not sure if it's what you want but I can't do better

Comment: Works fine to me. Are you including jquery and jquery UI? And do you include Jquery first and then jquery UI?

Comment: I think so I have `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")` on my _Layout.cshtml file

Comment: But I just checked that in my BundleConfig.cs, I have no entry for jqueryui, is it something ?

Comment: Yeah you should have somthing like bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js")); Also press F12 and check the console for errors

Comment: I added it but it's still not working :s

Comment: I added the CSS and jQuery UI from the CDN to your jsfiddle and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/qvt4zj9x/9/

Answer (score 1):

Well here is how I suggest you to do:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
    $("#locale").change(function() {
      var locale = $.datepicker.regional[$(this).val()];
      //destroy previose datapicker
      $("#datepicker").datepicker("destroy");
      //init new one
      $("#datepicker").datepicker(locale);
    });
  });

</script>

<select id="locale">
  <option val="fr">fr</option>
  <option val="en">en</option>
  <option val="ru">ru</option>
  <option val="de">de</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

I created [jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Teo_van_kot/qvt4zj9x/8/) from yours.

Note that you should add this i18n script to make it work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
```

You should add to your `head` this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><style type="text/css"></style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/themes/black-tie/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you but it's not my code which is not working, It's something with my imports and I can't find where the problem is...

Comment: @MrPixel6 you can just copy imports from example. And then find out where your problem is when by changing it's with your scripts one by one

Comment: I've copied every thing and it's still not working only have an empty input with no calendar :(

Comment: @MrPixel6 you should add to your head section what i mention in answer. And delete other jquery versions if they are exists check pls

Comment: Finally found it... I was right just wrong script imports... Thanks for the help !

Comment: @MrPixel6 no problem. Hope my example helps you.

Comment: Stay tuned new problems incoming ;p

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming that you got your answer above. However its awlays a best pracice to have script in a js file.

Lets say you create a js file like so:

```
$.myApplication = {

  init: function(){

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );

        $( "#locale" ).change(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option",
           $.datepicker.regional[ $( this ).val() ] );
        });     
  }

}
```

The view where you want to execute the script:

```
@section Scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $.myApplication.init();
        })
    </script>
    }
```

In your bundleconfig:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/CustomScripts").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/MyApp.js"));
```

layout:

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/CustomScripts")
```